# Ruby on Rails Active Record through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I've been trying got data from another table and it doesn't work.
I have three tables: **vacancies**, **resumes**, **connections**.

---

**vacancy.rb**

```
  has_many :connections
  has_many :resumes, through: :connections
```

**resume.rb**

```
  has_many :connections
  has_many :vacancies, through: :connections
```

**connection.rb**

```
  belongs_to :vacancy
  belongs_to :resume
```

**Resumes** and **Vacancies** tables has **id, name** columns

**Connections** table has **id**, **resume_id**, **vacancy_id** columns

My code - `@candidates = Resume.joins(:connections).where(connections: { vacancy_id: current_user.vacancies })`

It's showing data from Resume table, but I can't fetch it with Vacancies table. How can I output vacancy name for example? I tried `resume.connections.vacancy.name` in view but doesn't work -

```
undefined method `vacancy' for #<Connection::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0xb43ac9d8>
```

Comment: Can you include the code you have tried for accessing it via the Vacancies table?

Answer (score 0):

Ah - yes, that's just not going to work... you are calling "vacancy" on a *set* of connections... (arrays don't have a method called "vacancy" but each member of that array will). So: do you want to call "vacancy" on `each` connection? or do you want to `collect` the name of each vacancy from the *set* of collections?

try something like this instead:

```
vacancy_names = resume.connections.map{|con| con.vacancy.name }
```

alternatively:

```
resume.connections.each do |con| 
   puts con.vacancy.name
end
```

Comment: Yes, I want to collect this values. If I have in connection table _resume_id: 1_ and _vacancy_id: 2_, I want to get name of resume with id = 1 and name of vacancy with id = 2 in one array. But I don't know how get this values in my template.
`@candidates.connections.each` doesn't work. `undefined method connections' for #<Resume::ActiveRecord_Relation:0xb2c58de0>`



Code - `@candidates = Resume.joins(:connections).where(connections: { vacancy_id: current_user.vacancies })`

Comment: You seem to not realise you are calling methods on an Array of things, instead of on a single thing. A single candidate has the method `connections`, but an array of candidates does not have the method `connections`....  you must first call eg: `candidates[0].connections`. The `connections` call itself returns an array too. It will return an array even if there is only one connection in the database. You will then need to iterate through the array in order to get to the actual vacancies on each of the connections (see code above).